# ¿error cuando la sesion no esta inicada?

Tags: php, html, sql, session

Cuando no tengo la sesion iniciada , aparece este mensaje encima del sitio.quisiera que solo verifique si hay una session activa y elimine el mensaje sino.
tengo los require_once encima de todas las paginas relacionadas , asi que seria mas facil cambiar el config.php ,para que se aplique a las demas .

Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\manga\bin\config.php on line 4

html

```
<?php
    require_once("bin/clases.php"); 
    require_once("bin/config.php"); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
</html>
```

config.php

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    $consultaDatos = new Datos();
    $consulta = $consultaDatos->consultarDatos($_SESSION['usuario']);
?>
```

clase.php

```
<?php 
    class Conexion {
        protected $base;
        public function Conexion() {
            try{
                $this->base = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=MCDIELSCANS','root','');
                $this->base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                return $this->base;
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo "Error en la linea: " . $e->getline();
            }
        } 
    }
    class Datos extends Conexion {
        public function Datos(){
            parent::__construct();
        }
        public function inciarSesion($correo,$pass){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$correo' AND password = '$pass'";
            $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
            $statement->bindValue(':correo',$correo);
            $statement->bindValue(':password',$pass);
            $statement->execute(array());
            $cont = $statement->rowCount();
            $statement->closeCursor();
            return $cont;
        }
        public function consultarDatos($correo){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$correo'";
            $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute(array());
            $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
            $statement->closeCursor();
            return $resultado;
        }
        public function allUsuarios(){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
            $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
            $statement->execute(array());
            $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
            $statement->closeCursor();
            return $resultado;
        }
    
    }

?>
```

Comment: Al margen de tu error, deberías trabajar de forma completa con consultas preparadas, pues estás pasando directo las variables

Comment: Después de `session_start();` deberías verificar si existe la variable `if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) { /* Aquí consultas o muestras info del usuario */ }`

Comment: Gracias ,ya me funciona bien cambie el config.php a :<?php 
 session_start(); `<?php 
 session_start(); 
 if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) { $consultaDatos = new Datos();$consulta = $consultaDatos->consultarDatos($_SESSION['usuario']);}

?>`